# Looking for identity relating two angles in a triangle whose one side is twice in length as the other

Tags: geometry

[image]

I am basically looking for a relation between  $\alpha$ and $\theta$. The only one I could come up with(if I do remember correctly) is $\sin \alpha=2\sin \theta$

Comment: And $\sin\alpha = 2\sin\theta$ is the only relation that holds for sure in such a configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, your result is correct.

Applying sine rule in the given triangle as follows 
       $$\frac{\sin\alpha}{R}=\frac{\sin\theta}{\frac{R}{2}}$$
$$\frac{\sin\alpha}{R}=\frac{2\sin\theta}{R}$$$$\implies \sin \alpha=2\sin \theta$$

Comment: Didn't I write that already?

Comment: So, your result is correct